# How to tell the order of two datetime objects in python?

Tags: python

How can I tell which of two datetime objects come first, chronologically, in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<` operator.

```
if x < y:
    # x is before y
```

Or you can use the logical complement of the `>=` operator.

```
if not (x >= y):
    # x is before y
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the way you might expect

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d1 = datetime(2002, 03, 05)
>>> d2 = datetime(2009, 12, 22)
>>> d1 < d2
True
>>> d1 > d2
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `min` function:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime(2013,1,1)
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)
>>> min(d1,d2) 
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```